# Complex average calculation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have in my table values as the following:

```
MONTH  | value1 | value2|
-------|--------|-------|
2010/08|     0  |  700  |
2010/08|     0  |    0  |
2010/08| 41166  | 1500  |
2010/09|     0  |  700  |
2010/09|     0  | 1500  |
2010/09|     0  |    0  |
2010/10|     0  |    0  |
2010/10|     0  | 1500  |
2010/10|     0  |  700  |
2010/11|     0  |  700  |
2010/11|     0  |    0  |
2010/11|     0  | 1500  |
2010/11|     0  |    0  |
```

now this query returns me the sum of value2/value1 grouped by month

```
SELECT month, SUM(value2) / SUM(value1)*100 as percent
 GROUP BY month
------------------------
MONTH   |     PERCENT
--------|---------------
2010/08 |5,3442161006656
2010/09 |              0
2010/10 |              0
2010/11 |              0
```

what i want is to calculate the average which can be done this way :

```
SELECT AVG(percent) 
  FROM ( SELECT month, SUM(value2) / SUM(value1)*100 as percent
          GROUP BY month)
-------------
|AVG(percent)|
-------------|
|1,336       |
```

**but my problem is that i should not use a sub_query and should not use GROUP BY**, is it possible? Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: Why should you not use a subquery or GROUP BY? That sounds a bit arbitrary...

Comment: I don't think this will be possible (although I'm prepared for someone to correct me!). I think you will have to have at least two `SELECT` s to make this query work. Why do you have to work within this constraint?

Comment: For what database?  Analytics (OVER clause) *might* work, but I think your requirements need justification.

Comment: i need a calculation to use in ORACLE desktop for reporting , i have two worksheets, one grouped by month for Details and one without for Synthesis, thats why i cant use GROUP BY or else the two sheets became the same, and i cant use a subquery only a calculation

Comment: Pretty corny software package that doesn't let you use subqueries. Can't you define a view with subqueries and select from that?

Comment: Based on that data the query would fail because you can't divide by zero (sum(value1) is zero for three months). Can you clarify a bit further?

Comment: @Martin Schapendonk: It was just an example , I use decode in my original query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [COMPUTE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12014.htm):

```
COLUMN dummy NOPRINT
COMPUTE AVG OF percent ON dummy
BREAK ON dummy
SELECT NULL AS dummy, SUM(value2) / SUM(value1)*100 AS percent
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

This would generate a row with aggregated values below your query results.

Since I don't know Oracle I don't know if this particular syntax works for you. SQL Server has a [COMPUTE](http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2009/04/compute-transact-sql-sql-server-2005.html) clause though, which works slightly differently. I would be surprised if Oracle doesn't have something similar.